# Magnetic charge model

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

If we use want to calculate the magnetic charges of a bar magnet to calculate the Force between 2 magnets can we calculate them from the strength of the magnetic field of the magnet(B) and if yes how? (Assuming the magnetic charges are point like?)

Answer (score 0):

If the total flux out of the end of a magnet is $\Phi$ Webers, then the force on the pole in Newtons is ${\bf H}\Phi$ where the units of ${\bf H}$ are  Ampere (meter)$^{-1}$. If the magetic pole strength $q$ is measured in Ampere-meters, then the force in Newtons is $q{\bf B}$ where ${\bf B}$ is in Teslas. (conversion $\mu_0q=
\Phi$)

Comment: Can we relate the magnetic pole strength of a pole of a magnet to its magnetic field strength and if yes how?